# How to monetize my business community?

Tags: finance

I have created an online business community which has approx. 20 000 monthly pageviews. The functionality is similar to cragislist or quikr, online classified ads. I am trying to figure out how I can monetize my community. I have deployed the functionality to pay via paypal for video uploads but nobody uses it AFAIK. I'm thinking of adding maybe cryptocurrency features but I'm not sure what to burn the oil on. Can you tell me how I can monetize? I have adsense but the income from that is too low.

I see there is a similar question but I want to know more specific for my case.

[How can I introduce changes to cover costs without enraging the community?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-can-i-introduce-changes-to-cover-costs-without-enraging-the-community)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with getting to know your community better by finding out who they are,  what problems they face, what products and services they do buy and that includes things not related to your site. This can be done ideally over a drink and other options include calls, messaging and surveys.